# Converting Seconds to decimal

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We switched our database for Atlassain Jira from SQL Server to Oracle SQL. So now an older written script doesn't work due to syntax errors, and I'm trying to correct this. I didn't write the original so it is a little messy.
The original script was:

```
 SELECT innerdata.author,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),innerdata.workday, 106) as Work_Date,
         case
           when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .00 and .009 then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
           when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .01 and .25  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.25-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.25
           when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .26 and .50  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.50-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.50
           when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .51 and .75  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.75-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.75
           when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .76 and 1.00 then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,0))                                                                             --round to next whole number
         End as total_time
 FROM
 (
 SELECT worklog.author,
          CASE
                WHEN ((SELECT DATEPART(DW, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME))) IN(1) AND worklog.author = 'johnsmith') THEN CAST(FLOOR( CAST((worklog.startdate + 1) AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) 
                ELSE CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) 
                END AS workday,
                             timeworked
       FROM ivrsjira_prod.dbo.worklog
       WHERE CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-01-01',120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-01-01',120)
       AND worklog.author IN ('johnsmith')
 ) innerdata
 GROUP BY innerdata.author,innerdata.workday
 ORDER BY innerdata.author, innerdata.workday DESC;
```

The output data would present

```
AUTHOR   | Work_Date  | total_time
johnsmith| 01-JAN-2017| 5.5
johnsmith| 03-JAN-2017| 2.75
johnsmith| 05-JAN-2017| 9.25
```

The last column `total_time` was recorded into the table in a seconds format when you use the front end of JIRA. The script was written convert the number (rounding up) into quarter-hourly increments. For reports purposes.
This is the raw data of the table

```
ID |ISSUEID |AUTHOR    |GROUPLEVEL |ROLELEVEL |WORKLOGBODY |CREATED                 |UPDATEAUTHOR |UPDATED                 |STARTDATE               |TIMEWORKED
1  |3       |johnsmith |data       |data      |data        |01-JAN-2017 12:00:00 AM |johnsmith    |01-JAN-2017 12:00:00 AM |01-JAN-2017 12:00:00 AM |1200
```

So this is what I currently have after the updates made to my script.

```
SELECT innerdata.author,TO_CHAR(innerdata.workday, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as Work_Date,
    case
      when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .00 and .009 then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
      when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .01 and .25  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.25-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.25
      when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .26 and .50  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.50-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.5
      when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .51 and .75  then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + (.75-cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float)) --round to x.75
      when cast(right(CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),3) as float) between .76 and 1.00 then CAST(sum(Timeworked)/3600 AS DECIMAL(10,0))                                                                             --round to next highest whole number
    End as total_time
FROM
(SELECT worklog.author,
         CASE
               WHEN ((SELECT DATEPART(DW, CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME))) IN(1) AND worklog.author = 'orourkad') THEN CAST(FLOOR( CAST((worklog.startdate + 1) AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) 
               ELSE CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) 
               END AS workday,
                        timeworked
      FROM jira_ivrs.worklog
      WHERE CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME) BETWEEN TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'2017-01-01',120) AND TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'2017-01-01',120)
      AND worklog.author IN ('johnsmith')
) innerdata
GROUP BY innerdata.author,innerdata.workday
ORDER BY innerdata.author,innerdata.workday DESC;
```

But I now get the error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 102`
```

That is pointing directly to `IN(1)`.
So obviously it is giving me the errors due to the differences in syntax?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please. What is the data type of column `startdate`, `Timeworked`, `workday`. I assume most of these CAST/CONVERT are not needed.

Comment: What a complicated `CASE` expression - you could write it as single line: `TRUNC(Timeworked) + TRUNC((Timeworked-TRUNC(Timeworked)) / .25) * .25 as total_time` (assuming that is a `NUMBER`)

Comment: Please provide also the data types, i.e. table definition. And please edit your question instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated my original information. Sorry for the mess. A bit overworked at this exact moment.

Comment: And what do you expect as output from given example?

Comment: Added the output information.

Comment: I doubt the example output matches the example table data!

Comment: The output is only 3 columns, the user, date, and time worked. Just plug in the dates, and run it as a statement.

Comment: Your sample data is February 2018 but example output is January 2017. Please provide the table data which produces the example output. I am not going to dissect your select for this.

Comment: What is the purpose of `DATEPART(DW, CAST(FLOOR( CAST(worklog.startdate AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME))) IN(1)`? Compare with first day of week or first day of month?

Comment: Oh!!! I see what you are saying. That was a mistake in my typing. The example output is from an old report in 2017. But the example data is from the raw data from that specific table. Since the statement doesn't work now I can't get it to produce up-to-date example outputs.

Comment: Then you have to *explain* what you like to get. The naked query is just useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),innerdata.workday, 106)`
From oracle docs:

> CONVERT converts a character string from one character set to another.
>
> The char argument is the value to be converted. It can be any of the
>   datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB.
>
> The dest_char_set argument is the name of the character set to which
>   char is converted.
>
> The source_char_set argument is the name of the character set in which
>   char is stored in the database. The default value is the database
>   character set.

As I understood you need to convert field from date/time to varchar. In this case you can replace your `convert` with `to_char(innerdata.workday,'DD MON YYYY')`

3 HOURS LATER.

Ok. Looks like I understand what you need. Something like this one for inner select (Sorry, I haven't oracle near me last couple of years, so I can't test)

```
SELECT worklog.author,
        worklog.startdate+(CASE WHEN to_char(worklog.startdate,'DAY',
   'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as workday,
timeworked
FROM jira_ivrs.worklog
WHERE worklog.startdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('&&Start_date','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('&&End_date','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND worklog.author IN ('username')
```

JFYI in oracle date arithmetic is not so complex and you do not need to convert `date` to float. Just add 1 to date is increase date on 1 day and substracting 1/24 decrease date on one hour. [A pretty good article about date arithmetic](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_date_arithmetic.htm)

UPDATE 2.
I think that your query might looks like

```
    SELECT innerdata.author,trunc(workday),trunc(sum(timeworked)/3600)+trunc(mod(sum(timeworked),3600)/900)*0.25 total_time
FROM (
SELECT worklog.author,
        worklog.startdate+(CASE WHEN to_char(worklog.startdate,'DAY',
   'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')='7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as workday,
timeworked
FROM worklog
WHERE -- worklog.startdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('&&Start_date','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('&&End_date','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
-- AND 
worklog.author IN ('username')) innerdata
group by innerdata.author,trunc(workday)
order by 1,2
```

Small comments:

1. In oracle dow for sunday is 7 in this expression.
2. trunc(workday) "converts" datetime to date

Comment: See, that is what I thought. But I still couldn't get it to work. Let me give it a shot, and see what I can produce.

Comment: Sure. As I understand you use `convert` in many places. Could you please provide description of `dbo.worklog` table? At least for columns that you only needed

Comment: I replaced all of the converts, and I still got an error. But the next error pointed to the  IN(1). Oracle SQL stated there should be a "from" because it is a select statement. But now I'm confused. I've been working on this for roughly 2 days, along with other reports to re-write and I've just got my mind boggled at this point.

Both of the schemas have the same columns in the respective table: ID, ISSUEID, AUTHOR, GROUPLEVEL, ROLELEVEL, WORKLOGBODY, CREATED, UPDATEAUTHOR, UPDATED, STARTDATE, TIMEWORKED

Comment: I slightly modified my answer

Comment: Another question. Your need to convert timeworked from seconds to hours in quoter-hour resolution? Something like this:
 3h10m to 3
 2h 20m to 2.25
1h 35m to 1.5
9h 50m to 9.75?

Comment: Well technically speaking it is in two parts. For a sister department they need these to be rounded up to the quarter-hour for our clients and billing. For my department, they can just be rounded to the whole number like 3h10m. So if I can get one to work, I can re-write it for our specific reports.

Comment: So, for quoter-hour resolution you can use something like this:
`trunc(timeworked/3600)+trunc(mod(timeworked,3600)/900)*0.75`. I think this expression is much simpler

Comment: And last, but not least. Oracle denies to use `GROUP BY` without aggregate function in `SELECT` clause. So my question is "Why you used `GROUP BY` in this SELECT?"

Comment: So when you'd run it without that group by, it presents `Column 'innerdata.author' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: `to_char(worklog.startdate,'DAY',
   'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')` returns weekday name but never a number as `1` - and what do you mean by `numeric date language`?

Comment: As I know it is little hard to get day of week as a number in Oracle. I'd got this code from http://www.dba-oracle.com/sql_convert_day_of_week_to_number.htm
And now I've check this code with oracle live sql:
`select to_char(sysdate,'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') from dual`


`TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''NUMERICDATELANGUAGE''')
5`

Comment: I was not aware of this *undocumented* NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE - however, using undocumented functions is a risk. Better use `WHEN TO_CHAR(worklog.startdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American') = 'MON'`

Comment: I apologize for typo. Use `trunc(timeworked/3600)+trunc(mod(timeworked,3600)/900)*0.25` instead of `trunc(timeworked/3600)+trunc(mod(timeworked,3600)/900)*0.75`

Comment: Using that latest statement actually works, and pulls all the data summed pretty much as needed. The two bugs that I can see, is it doesn't take the time, and add it to the next day based off of when the time started. So for me as a 3rd shift employee the time started at 11pm would then be added to the next day. The other bug is the addition itself, so the raw data pulls 2100 seconds, which is 35 minutes, so it should round to .75 instead of .30. But these are tiny issues, and they can be accepted no problem. Thank you so much for the help!